# Dynamic tree structure using javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make familytree like image uploaded here. Can any one tell me how can I set left and top of div so, It will not overlap on div? I want javascript to set left and top so, It will not overlap on each other and perfectly display.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Actually, I want to make this kind of structure dynamically.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**jQuery Org Chart**](https://th3silverlining.com/2011/12/01/jquery-org-chart-a-plugin-for-visualising-data-in-a-tree-like-structure/), a plugin for visualising data in a tree-like structure.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamai.net](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/4b9fddaac057cc533324300f2b7ae1b5b13d007f/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f54386b4b412e706e67))</sub>

And you can change options to display the trees in left, right and top too! `:)`

Comment: How Can I add 2 div on single div using this library? see, image above jimit div got two divs on upper side. I think it is not possible with this library.

Comment: @Jimit Check out their [documentation](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart#readme). It has the exact thing you need.

Comment: I want structure exactly like my 2nd image and In documentation it is not mentioned we can do something like this.

Comment: @Jimit Try this one, may be: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#Example

Comment: It will not work for this kind of hierarchy